# Set First Value as Key in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Creating an array based off selected DataTables Rows

```
$('#savenlp').click(recordjourney);

function recordjourney() {
var data = table.rows(['.selected']).data().toArray();
console.log( (data) );
console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
}
```

`data` returns

```
0 : (8) ["Which", "TitleCase", "QuestionWord", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

`JSON.stringify(data)` returns

```
[["baseball","Noun","Singular","","","","",""]]
```

This information is dynamically generated, so I am just looking to take the first value (in this case `baseball`) and turn it into something like

```
  "baseball": [
    "Noun",
    "Singular"
  ]
```

I can return the first value (the key I want using)

```
alert(data[0][0]);
```

I am much more adept in PHP but I am learning javascript/jquery more and more.

It is my understanding javascript does not have associative arrays, so I am a bit confused as to how to generate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  ["baseball","Noun","Singular","","","","",""],
  ["baseballs","Noun","","Plural","","","","",]
];
const mappedData = data.reduce((acc, row) => { acc[row.shift()] = row.filter(d => d !== ''); return acc; }, {});
console.log(mappedData);
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use object destructuring and spread operators for ease of use.
In the example below, the `key` will be the first item and all the rest items will be placed in the `newData` variable

```js
const data = [["baseball","Noun","Singular","","","","",""]];
const [key, ...newData] = data[0]
// if you want the new data to not have empty entries, simple apply the filter
const newDataFiltered = newData.filter(item => !!item)
const objWithEmpty = {[key]: newData}
const objWithoutEmpty = {[key]: newDataFiltered}


console.log(objWithEmpty, objWithoutEmpty)
```

For multiple arrays inside the outer array, just enclose the whole logic inside a for loop

```js
const data = [
  ["baseball","Noun","Singular","","","","",""],
  ["baseball1","Noun1","Singular1","","","","",""],
  ["baseball2","Noun2","Singular2","","","","",""]
];
const objWithEmpty = {}
const objWithoutEmpty = {}

data.forEach((array) => {
  const [key, ...newData] = array
  // if you want the new data to not have empty entries, simple apply the filter
  const newDataFiltered = newData.filter(item => !!item)
  objWithEmpty[key] = newData
  objWithoutEmpty[key] = newDataFiltered
})

console.log(objWithEmpty, objWithoutEmpty)
```

Comment: Lots of great answers but this one I am liking best! Thank you everyone.

Comment: Actually this one doesn't work with more than one array. @generalhenry one line answer now seems best.

Comment: @BrianBruman just enclosing the whole logic inside a `forEach` statement would solve your problem. That being said, the answer selected is indeed elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply extract the desired values from `data` and put them into an object formatted as you like:

```js
const data = [["baseball","Noun","Singular","","","","",""]];
const firstArr = data[0];
const transformedFirstObject = {
  [firstArr[0]]: [firstArr[1], firstArr[2]],
};
console.log(transformedFirstObject);
```

But it's pretty weird to have an object with only one property like that. If your `data` might have more than one sub-array in it and you want to turn the array of arrays into an array of objects, use `map`:

```js
const data = [
  ["baseball","Noun","Singular","","","","",""],
  ["foo","bar","baz","","","","",""]
];

const transformed = Object.assign(...data.map(([prop, value1, value2]) => ({ [prop]: [value1, value2] })));
console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit simpler compared to other answers here but works as well.

```js
const data = [
  ["baseball","Noun","Singular","","","","",""],
  ["baseball1","Noun1","Singular1","","","","",""],
  ["baseball2","Noun2","Singular2","","","","",""]
];

const obj = [];
data.forEach(function(i) {
  let jsonObj = {};
  jsonObj [i[0]] = i.slice(1).filter(x=>x !='');
  obj.push(jsonObj)
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: You should use `j.slice(1, j.length)`.

Comment: Actually, `j.slice(1);` would be more than sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

Just using `forEach`, considering multiple array elements.

```js
var obj = {};
var arr = [
  ["baseball", "Noun", "Singular", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["Test", "Test1", "Test2", "", "", "", "", ""]
];

arr.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  val.forEach(function(val1, idx1) {
    if (idx1 === 0) {
      obj[val1] = val.slice(1, val.length)
    }
  })
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```